# Can we change the html or body height using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run this statement: `$('body').height(100);` but when I check the height again, I find it unchanged!

Is there any way to change the height of the `<body>`?

Answer (score 6):

document body is a magical element and does not behave the way other HTML elements do. Your code:

```
$('body').height(100);
```

Is correct and it is same as:

```
$('body').css({height: 100});
$('body').css({height: '100px'});
$('body').attr({style: 'height: 100px'});
```

All result in this:

```
<body style="height: 100px;">
```

However, setting the height will not *hide* the area outside the 100px height invisible. You should wrap the body content inside a div and set its height instead:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery solution would be:

```
$("body").wrapInner($('<div id="height-helper"/>').css({
    height: 100,
    overflow: "hidden"
}));
```

Comment: I have tried it as well, when I set the height of the wrapper, its height got changes but the body was remaining the same, and to ensure, body was already wrapped in a wrapper

Comment: See edited answer. Set `height: 100px; overflow: hidden;` on the wrapper. I believe this is what you want. overflow can also be set to scroll.

Comment: Just a note for the last code: if you want to set back the original state use this: `$('#height-helper').contents().unwrap();`

Answer (score 3):

You should actually use

`$('body').css('height', '100');` and it will work.

Comment: It is working in firefox but when I tried using it in iOS browser, it is not working :-/

Comment: Use this instead $('body').css('height', '100px');

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('body').addClass('your class name');` or `$('body').attr('style', 'height: 100px');`

Comment: $('body').attr('style', 'height: 100px'); It is not working as well
 see
>>> $('body').height();
416
>>> $('body').attr('style', 'height: 100px');
[body]
>>> $('body').height();
416

Comment: What I have seen in many browsers is that you add the following in css style `<style type="text/css"> html, body { height: 100% } </style>` which will always show the height as 100%, so if you change it with jquery you should run it in a $(document).ready to ensure that the DOM has created before changing the size. Also if there are css style involved they might override your inline style (shouldn't but possible). So try `height: 100px !important`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$('body').css('height', '100px');
```

Or

```
$('body').height(100);
```

Comment: see $('body').height(100); is not working in browser itself and $('body').css('height', '100px'); is working in browser but not in iOS browser, I want it to be working in both