# Changing the html or body height using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I tryed [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410101/can-we-change-the-html-or-body-height-using-jquery) answer but in my Chome it doesn't works( I still have a lot of [free space](http://pantograph-mebel.ru/) under my content. What can be a problem?

Comment: Can u add you code please?

Comment: Add links in your question to make people understand it better, not to find the question itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the tag `<canvas id="arrow_under_slides" height="20" width="1000">` they all seem to display nothing. **[EDIT]** *(They were displaying, but the position: relative moved their location.  A position:absolute fixes the problem in this case.)*

**[EDIT]** *This is working code for the arrow-right-content tag as an example, but all of the canvas tags must be changed to position: absolute with the correct top and left values*

```
<canvas id="arrow_right_content" height="814" width="20" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 1182px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: they are useful! try deleting them with firebug and you see the arows disappear from content!

Comment: I think I was seeing doubles. There are half the ammount of tags as the first time I looked... But I think they're still you're problem.  Don't use position: relative.

Comment: When you use position: relative, the item still takes up space in its original position, and therefore is stretching the body.  Position relative only moves where the tag is displayed. I would use position: absolute, or fixed.  Fixed will scroll with the page, so don't do that if you're wanting them to be at that EXACT position all the time.

This will require some math to fix position locations, but it will fix your problem!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp might be a helpful link to explain the situation.

Comment: @user1447420 If you can, let me know if this answer helped you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try `min-height` in your CSS

Or with jQuery

`$('body').css('min-height', '400px');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$('html, body').css('height', '100%');`

Answer (score -1):

the free space is caused by canvas elements you have there.by the way use this css codes to avoid getting free space:

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    height: 1700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you must specify body height if you change it!