# Input field blur event firing immediately after focus on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, mobile

On a site I'm working on, I have a custom search field that the user wants in different places depending on the device. It's a WordPress site and the search is starting off in the header menu. On mobile, it's being moved above the title area/hamburger menu. They also have specifications that the field itself should be hidden until a button is clicked, at which point the field is displayed.

On desktop, before the search form is moved around the DOM, everything is working fine. But on mobile devices, and after the input field itself has been displayed, the blur event is firing about 200ms after the focus event.

After reading this answer: [Input field immediately blurs after focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661772/input-field-immediately-blurs-after-focus), my guess is that moving the search element around the DOM is causing the issue, but I can't figure out how to fix that without just creating two identical search fields and hiding one depending on screen width. The question/answer I linked doesn't quite fit my scenario the same way, so it didn't really help me get to a solution.

Here's my actual form:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <div class="search-form-inner">
    <input type="search" value="" name="s" id="s" class="search-form-field" placeholder="Search keolisamericas.com">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search-form-submit search-form-toggle" value="">
    <span class="search-form-close search-form-toggle"><span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's the code that's moving the form:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 900) {
    var $search = $(".genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.search");

    $search.detach();
    $(".mobile-top-header-nav").prepend($search);
}
```

**Edit:** For now, I'm just going with a temporary solution of having two identical forms on the page, and hiding/unhiding them with CSS depending on the screen size. I'd love a more elegant solution than that, and to figure out what's causing my issue to begin with.

Comment: Have you tried moving it, not detaching and attaching it again?

Comment: @Taplar, yeah I've tried that and got the same problem.

Comment: Please show us the code that is attaching the events for `blur` and `focus`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLemmi Maybe I'm talking about it wrong, but I just mean the default blur and focus events that occur when you click on an input field on a webpage. I'm not writing anything that specifically sets those events. Unless you mean the event messages that come up in the console when I log the events that fire when you click on the input.

Comment: Got it! But could you add some listeners for `blur` and `focus` through code, like `input.addEventListener('focus', function() { console.log('focus') });` and see if it also causes `blur` to fire? I think that the way that you are debugging this is what is actually causing the issue, as chrome inspector (or whatever you're using) will provoke the blur when debugging the `focus` event.

Comment: Thanks! I gave that a shot and yes blur is still firing then. It fires regardless of if I'm debugging it with anything or not, so I don't think that's what's causing it.

Comment: @KreigD Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am experiencing the same thing, but it only happens at a particular resolution and zoom level.  Im using a Galax s9+, and setting the res to FHD, and the screen zoom to the middle causes it.  Change either of those settings and it doesn't happen.